# Working out if a phase bullet is contained or within a body

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d, collision-detection

Bottom is a picture demonstration.

I'm using Box2D with LibGDX.

Basically I have a 'phase' bullet that's random sizes. The phase bullet goes though objects and is set as a sensor.

My problem is, Libgdx or Box2d doesn't have a simple function like "isBodyColliding", so I tried to implement my own (doesn't work):

```
@Override
    public void update(float update) {
        super.update(update);

        this.countdownTillNextHit.reduceTime(update);

        if(this.countdownTillNextHit.isComplete())
        {
            this.countdownTillNextHit.start(this.hitTimer);

            GameController.getInstance().getWorld().QueryAABB(new QueryCallback() {
                @Override
                public boolean reportFixture(Fixture fixture)
                {
                    if(fixture.getBody().getUserData() != null && fixture.getBody().getUserData() instanceof LivingObject)
                    {
                        LivingObject livingObject = ((LivingObject) fixture.getBody().getUserData());
                        if(livingObject.getLongestBox2D() > getLongestBox2D())
                        {
                            if(fixture.testPoint(getBody().getWorldCenter()))
                            {
                                for(PhaseHitInterface phaseHitInterface : phaseHitInterfaceArray)
                                {
                                    phaseHitInterface.hitLivingObjectRepeat(livingObject);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if(getBody().getFixtureList().first().testPoint(livingObject.getBody().getWorldCenter()))
                            {
                                for(PhaseHitInterface phaseHitInterface : phaseHitInterfaceArray)
                                {
                                    phaseHitInterface.hitLivingObjectRepeat(livingObject);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    return false;
                }
            },
                this.getBody().getPosition().x - (getWidthBox2d() / 2f), //Lower left x
                this.getBody().getPosition().y - (getHeightBox2d() / 2f), //Lower left y,
                this.getBody().getPosition().x + (getWidthBox2d() / 2f),
                this.getBody().getPosition().y + (getWidthBox2d() / 2f)
            );

        }
```

I have tried using begin contact and end contact with arrays to keep track of what's in and out of the area but endContact doesn't get call resulting in the array getting larger because of the references to previous objects.

Can someone help me out here?

[image: Phase Bullet Image]

Comment: Implmenting whole function in update method is bad, bad, bad. And why don't you use ContactListener?

Comment: Game still runs at 60fps with over 40 items. I know what you mean though. Yeah but the problem is, it doesn't always fire 'endContact' with sensors.

Comment: If EndContact is not triggered it would be a bug in libGDX, which seems a little unlikely. I get the feeling you might not be checking the contact listener correctly. Perhaps you could post that code too.

Comment: It would be nice to have a solution though. Even if EndContact & BeginContact are working. Thanks.